# HTML5 Local Database Insert

Tags: javascript, database, html, local

I'm having trouble inserting multiple records into an HTML5 Database.  I verified the schema is properly being inserted.

Am I calling it in an invalid manner?

```
    // Ajax Call to Get Users function
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Handlers/UserHandler.php",
        data: "method=getAllUsers",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            database.db.transaction(function (tx) {
                for (var id in data) {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO contacts(id, fname, lname, email, loginId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [id , data[id].FirstName, data[id].LastName, data[id].Email, data[id].LoginId]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database should be opened before executing any SQL inserts within the transaction. To open a connection to the database just call the function `openDatabase` to get the `db` object:

```
db = window.openDatabase(dbName<string>, dbVersion<string>, dbDescription<string>, dbSize<int>);
```

An optional 5h parameter is allowed, passing a callback function to be called after the database is created.

If the database was already opened, can you give more information about the error or behaviour you are obtaining?